# Why does Android studio provide different values for sizeof(long) at runtime compared to compiletime or during preprocessing

Tags: c, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm using Android Studio(64-Bit version) on Windows 7(64-Bit) & building native library using Android-NDK (with the help of Cmake). Below is the smallest breakdown of my problem.

I'm using the value of sizeof(long) as the size for one of my arrays in the native C code. Android studio is behaving differently at runtime compared to compiletime. I'm printing the value of sizeof(long) in a log statement & it prints 4. Now, for one of my requirement, I need to declare an array as

char c[4 - sizeof(long)];

I know this looks weird, but this is a breakdown of my bigger problem. Actually we are using the sizeof some structures for allocating the size of some arrays & the structure has some long variables which are causing issues & wrong sizes.

The above declaration is throwing an error saying 'Array length can't be negative' & when I change the value to 8, i.e., when I declare the array as

char c[8 - sizeof(long)];

the error is gone, so the sizeof(long) is being populated to 8 by the Android Studio & is throwing a pre-processor error for values less than 8, and if I ignore the pre-processor error & go ahead with compilation, then the compiler throws up the same error. But the value of sizeof(long) in the debug print statement below is 4.

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "log", "Sizeof(long): %d", sizeof(long));  // This prints Sizeof(long): 4

I have set the macro to build 32Bit native libraries in my CMakeLists.txt file, by using set(TARGET_PREFER_32_BIT 1).

Can anyone please help me out with this issue, Is there anything additional required to be done in Android Studio project setup to get the sizeof(long) to be 4 at pre-processor level? Is there anything else to be done for building 32-Bit native libraries? Any help will be very appreciated.

Adding additional info based on few comments:

1. My gradle.properties has just one line. *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m* & the build.gradle has the below bulid types:
   *buildTypes { release { minifyEnabled false proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' } }*
2. Error when compiled:

app\src\main\cpp\native-lib.cpp:2496:12: error: 'c' declared as an array with a negative size

3. And when I meant that there's an error with preprocessing, its the error highlighted by the 'Android Studio' IDE saying 'Array length can't be negative'. Apologies if the earlier statement was confusing.
4. Printing using  %zu instead of %d in the log statement also prints 4.

Comment: What does your `abiFilters` look like?

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal Compilable Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: `4-sizeof(long)` cannot be negative, bevause the result of `sizeof` is unsigned. An error message saying it is may be the result of a poorly written message. Quite possibly the value is zero (which is not allowed), and the message is wrong.

Comment: The preprocessor, as specified in the C standard, does not evaluate or replace `sizeof` expressions. In light of this, your statements about the preprocessor “throwing” errors are perplexing. You should include exact error message text in your question, along with the MCVE.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: _"Quite possibly the value is zero (which is not allowed)"_. It depends. GCC allows it as an extension. Not sure about Clang.

Comment: [#include <stdint.h>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html)

Comment: My gradle.properties has just one line. _org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m_ & the build.gradle has the below bulid types:     _buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }_

Comment: Printing values of type `size_t` as if they're `int` (which I happily assume is what `%d` means) is not a good idea, unless you cast. The standard printing functions use `%zu` for `size_t`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me like the whole point to of that `char` array is to ensure either that the struct size is a multiple of 4 bytes, or that the next member is aligned on a 4 byte boundary. If so, can't you just use `#pragma pack` and/or `__attribute__((aligned` instead?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, we are using __attribute__((aligned... to pack the structure. Our basic intention is to throw a compilation error when the size of a particular structure is greater than some size. So, we are declaring an array as *char c[MAX_SIZE - sizeof(struct S) + 1]* so that, if the sizeof(struct S) exceeds MAX_SIZE+1, we get a compilation error. And we are using __attribute__((aligned.. to pack the structure. Our structure S has a good number of long variables, so the sizeof(struct S) is getting calculated wrongly.

Comment: @Michael: What I have mentioned in my above comment is our actual requirement & I have provided the breakdown of the problem. So, in our case, lets say that we allow the max size of our structure to be 100. so MAX_SIZE=100, If our structure S, has variables other than 'long' which take up size of 100 bytes, then sizeof(struct S) will be 100 and things work as expected. If there is a single 'long' variable in our struct S, then the sizeof(struct S) is more than 100 by 4 bytes. So I tried printing the sizeof(long). And we are using the __attribute__((packed)) for our structures.

Comment: Well, is `MAX_SIZE` large enough so that it will work for `sizeof(long) == 8`? If not, you might not be able to build your library for 64-bit ABIs, and you need to limit the ABIs you build for with `abiFilters`. Note that this isn't a long-term solution, since in August 2019 you will be required to have 64-bit versions of any 32-bit libraries included in your app.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks a lot for the info about the 64-bit versions timeline (will take it up with the stake holders). Currently we want to build only the 32-bit libraries (all of them are native libraries). So, I have provided *set(TARGET_PREFER_32_BIT 1)* in my CMakeLists.txt file. Please let me know if this is not sufficient.

Comment: I don't know what `TARGET_PREFER_32_BIT` does. But the normal way to limit which ABIs to build and/or package for in an Android project is to use `abiFilters` inside your `build.gradle` script.

Comment: @Michael: Thank you Michael, I have made changes to use the abiFilters in my build.gradle, but there are still issues with the sizeof() the structure.